# This D. E. is a homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm confused with this differential equation. I read this in a post and in an example in a book.

Cite:

The best and the simplest test for checking the homogeneity of a differential equation is as follows :-->

Take for example we have to solve 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+ (x^2+y^2)^\frac12}{x}$$

1. Put $x=ax$ and $y=ay$ where a is any arbitrary constant.
2. Now from the numerator and denominator take the constant as common with maximum power possible from both numerator and denominator each.
3. If the constant gets cancelled throughout and we obtain the same equation again then that particular differential equation is homogeneous and the the power of constant which remains after cutting it to lowest degree is the degree of homogeneity of that equation.

QUESTION: What's happens if $\alpha<0$. I though a possible problem with homogeneity definition because $\sqrt{\alpha^2}=|\alpha|=-\alpha\not=\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differential equation is not homogeneous but "positively homogeneous".  Still, the ansatz $y(x) = x u(x)$ will work (separately for $x > 0$ and $x < 0$).